# Using Divergence Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $B_r$ denote the ball $|x|\le r$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and write $dS_r$ for the area element on its boundary $\partial B_r$. The electric field associated with a uniform charge distribution on $\partial B_R$ may be expressed as 
$$E(x)=C\int\limits_{\partial B_R}\nabla_x|x-y|^{-1}dS_y,$$
**a)** Show that for any $r<R$, the electric flux $\int\limits_{\partial B_r}E(x).\nu dS_x$ through $\partial B_r$ equals zero.

**b)**Show that $E(x)\equiv 0$ for $|x|<R$("a conducting spherical shell shields its interior from outside electrical effects").

For part a, I tried to to using divergence theorem as follows:
$$\int\limits_{\partial B_r}E(x).\nu dS_x=\int\limits_{B_r}divE(x)dx= C\int\limits_{B_r}\int\limits_{B_R}div\nabla_x|x-y|^{-1}dS_ydx,$$
However, I don't know how to proceed next steps to prove the integrand is zero. By the way, could you please suggest me a method for part b)?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\Phi\pars{\vec{R}} & \equiv \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}
{1 \over \root{R^{2} + r^{2} - 2rR\cos\pars{\theta}}}\,\
\overbrace{r^{2}\sin\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta\,\dd\phi}^{\ds{\dd S}} 
\\[5mm] & =
\left.\vphantom{\huge A}-\,{2\pi r \over R}
\root{R^{2} + r^{2} - 2rR\cos\pars{\theta}}
\right\vert_{\ \theta\ = 0}^{\ \theta\ =\ \pi} =
-\,{2\pi r \over R}\,\pars{R + r - \verts{R - r}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbox[#ffe,10px,border:1px dashed navy]{\ds{\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{-4\pi r} & \mbox{if} & \ds{R} & \ds{<} & \ds{r} 
\\[2mm]
\ds{-\,{4\pi r^{2} \over R}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{R} & \ds{>} & \ds{r} 
\end{array}\right.}}
\end{align}

> - When $\ds{\color{#f00}{R < r}}$, the potential $\ds{\Phi\pars{\vec{R}}}$ is $\ds{\vec{R}}$-independent
>     such that the *Electric Field*
>     $\ds{\vec{\mrm{E}}\pars{R} = -\nabla_{\vec{R}}\Phi\pars{\vec{R}} = \vec{0}}$.
> - When $\ds{\color{#f00}{R > r}}$, 
>     $\ds{\vec{\mrm{E}}\pars{R} = -\nabla_{\vec{R}}\Phi\pars{\vec{R}} =
>   4\pi r^{2}\,{\vec{R} \over R^{3}} \not= \vec{0}}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you give me a hint for part b,?