# Computing the electric flux

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $B_r=\{x\in \mathbb R^3 : |x|\le r\}$ and let $dS_r$ denote the area element on $\partial B_r$. Set $$E(x)=C\int_{\partial B_R}\nabla_x |x-y|^{-1} dS_y$$

Show that for $|x|< R$, $E$ is zero and for $r<R$, the flux $\int_{\partial B_r} E(x)\cdot \nu \ dS_x$ is zero.

First of all, what does $\nabla_x$ stand for? The $\nabla$ without subscripts usually stands for the gradient, but I'm not sure about $\nabla_x$.

For the flux integral, is it better to use the divergence theorem or use the definition? In the former case, how do I find the divergence (i.e., how to differentiate a line integral)?

Comment: $\nabla_x$ means that you're taking the gradient of $$\Bbb R^3\setminus \{y\}\ni x\mapsto |x-y|^{-1} \in \Bbb R$$instead of the gradient of the full map $$(\Bbb R^3\times \Bbb R^3)\setminus \{(x,x)\mid x\in \Bbb R^3\}\ni (x,y)\mapsto |x-y|^{-1}\in\Bbb R. $$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992071/using-divergence-theorem

Answer (score 1):

Here $E(x)$ is the electric field of a surface charge on a sphere. The second result is Gauss's law applied to $B_r$. The first result then follows by symmetry.

Comment: I was hoping there is some non-physical method of solution...

Comment: @user5579085: Well, all of that can be expressed purely mathematically; I just put it in physical terms because that to me makes it easier to think about it. Theoretically you don't need to know any physics to apply the corresponding theorems. Gauss's law is the divergence theorem.